# Setup UICollectionViewLayout to match a column split UITableView like result

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm new to UICollectionView in iOS 6 and so far it seems like it's pretty much like a UITableView however I'm trying to figure out a way to make the pagingEnabled feel of a UISCrollview work with a set of cells I'm displaying as if they were a UITableView (when actually they are not)

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

My questions is how to layout cell in that form, I understand I have to subclass UICollectionViewLayout but quite don't understand how to achieve this, and how to enable the paging at the same time, if it must be enabled by the UICollectionViewLayout or should I do that myself.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override one of `UICollectionViewLayout` method, like `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` for example.

In this method, you will do some math calculations to determine your cell position.
For your case, cell at index 0 will be at (0,0), index 1 at (0, 10), [...] index 11 at (100, 0), etc.
Your calculations will depends on some variable like how many cell in one column, space between column, ...

Once you did that, return a `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` class with appropriates properties (`frame`, `size`, etc)